# Replacing Date within string Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, datetime, datetime-format

I am not very good with regex and am having difficult understanding how to implement it to solve my problem.
 Basically I have a file name which will feature today's date in its name and I would like to replace it with yesterdays date.

```
var fName = "XX_YYYYYYYYYY_ZZZZZZ_2013-09-25_QQQQQ_IIII.xml";
```

I need to replace the part 2013-09-24 
so that the new file name would be

> XX_YYYYYYYYYY_ZZZZZZ_2013-09-24_QQQQQ_IIII.xml

This is how I formated the date:

```
String dateToday = String.Format("{0: yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Today)
string dateLast = String.Format("{0: yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1))
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a regex for this, just use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) e.g.

```
var fName = "XX_YYYYYYYYYY_ZZZZZZ_2013-09-25_QQQQQ_IIII.xml";
var newName = fName.Replace(String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Today), String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Today.AddDays(-i)));
```

You have whitespace in your formatting condition, in order for this to work you need to remove that i.e. replace `{0: yyyy-MM-dd}` with `{0:yyyy-MM-dd}`.

See this [example](http://ideone.com/raD0KS)

Comment: That was my first thought but it doesn't change anything when I run it

Comment: Really nice alternative to Regex.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following...

```
var fName = "XX_YYYYYYYYYY_ZZZZZZ_2013-09-25_QQQQQ_IIII.xml";
var newFName= Regex.Replace(fName, DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```